# Embedded JavaApplet to get full path to file

Tags: java, html, web-applications, applet

For a company internal webapp I need a way to access the full path of files on our internal fileserver that the user drag n drops on a dropzone on the website. As the fileserver is mounted in a similar manner on the webserver the path will point to the same file on its side and I can further process the files.

As that is not possible with plain HTML/Java-Script because of security reasons I did some research and it seems, that one viable way to accomplish this would be to embed a java-applet in the HTML code of the website. However .. as this would be my first encounter with java I'd like to confirm if that is actually possible before starting out.

Or alternatively another way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Applets are deprecated.

Comment: Well .. won't question that. Do you have an alternative way to get the full filepath?

Comment: You can use Java Web Start instead: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/